# Quartz: The Scheduler has been shutdown

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have developed a small Java application in which i use the Quartz.jar library.

But when executing my application and calling Quartz, I get the following error message in my console:

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: The Scheduler has been shutdown
```

I have no idea where it comes from and what causes the error.

Has anyone an idea what the solution to this could be?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you do in code. Please, provides some examples to figure out what is going on. Also Quartz has a lot of example, please check if you are doing everything correctly. [Here is examples](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example1.html)

Comment: Hi RazorAlliance192, it's been over a month since you posted this question and I answered it. If you found my answer to be of any help, it'd be nice of you to mark it as accepted (the check under the voting arrows). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't edit the question to include the code for "*executing my application and calling Quartz*", it's going to be ***really*** hard to tell exactly what could be happening.

*However*, it may have something to do with [this little caveat](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/ShutdownScheduler.html) about calling `Scheduler.shutdown()`:

> Once you have shutdown a scheduler, it cannot be restarted

It might be that you are trying to `start()` a scheduler that was already shutdown, hence the error.

But once again, can't really tell if you don't include the related code.